# Selling after best before date (Belgium/Netherlands)

Tags: laws, belgian-beers

I regularly buy beers online in December, mainly from Belgium (and Netherlands). Are there any laws about selling beers after best before date (with no notice to potential customers)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no law infringements in selling beers with past Best Before Date.
EU allows it. A new regulation is awaited by 2021, but the direction is to avoid food waste. Best practice should be the replacement.